# Finding & filling in other Excel sheets based on criteria using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with four worksheets: Overview, apple, banana and pear.
In the sheet overview I have a 3x3 table:

```
        In      Out      Extra
apple   
banana  
pear
```

Cell H5 in Overview contains a date of 2019, which can be selected via a drop-down menu

In each of the apple/banana/pear sheets, I have a 365x3 table:

```
               In      Out        Extra
1-1-2019
2-1-2019
3-1-2019
.
.
.
31-12-2019
```

I would like to run a macro so that the In, Out and Extra values from the Overview sheet are filled in the correct worksheet and behind the correct date in that worksheet.

The goal would be that people fill in the overview sheet (In, Out and Extra values as well as a date), they run the macro, and data is automatically stored in the right cell in the right worksheet.

This is a relatively easy example, the actual workbook for which I need this macro has more that 70 "fruits".

I know the code below doesn't work, but I'll hope to show my way of thinking

```
Sub export()

Dim ws As Worksheet             'worksheet
    Dim currentdate As Date         'datum
    Dim fruit As String             'Fruit

    Worksheets("Overview").Activate                 'activate worksheet Overview
    currentdate = ActiveSheet.Cells(H5)             'select date value
fruit = Overview.Range(“C6, C8”)                'select range of the fruits


    For Each ws In Worksheets                           'loop over every worksheet except the Overview sheet
        If ws.Name = fruit Then                         'crossreference name worksheet with fruit in Overview sheet
            ws.Activate                                 'activating the selected worksheet
            If ws.Range("A1:A365") = currentdate Then   'looking for the correct date in the selcted worksheet
                fruit = ws.Name
    Next ws

    End Sub
```

Comment: hi. to start u can replace "If ws.Name = fruit Then"   to "If ws.Name <> "Overview" Then ". this will skipp the sheet overview and get all the others

Comment: Do you really need an VBA solution for this? It can be done with normal Excel formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vba solution for this:

For this solution to work properly, you should make the sheets APPLE, BANANA and PEAR share same structure. In my example, all this 3 sheets have in column A the date, column B is `IN`, column C is `OUT` and column D is `EXTRA`

Also, in OVERVIEW sheet, make sure the terms APPLE, BANANA and PEAR are **exactly** equal to names of each sheet (this means no extra spaces, blanks or different chars).

And OVERVIEW must be the active sheet.

[image]

My button IMPORT is linked to this code to import data. I want to import data from 17/05/2019 (the yellow rows)

```
Sub IMPORT_DATA()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("B2:D4").Clear

Dim i As Long
Dim TargetRow As Long
Dim TargetSheet As String
Dim TargetDate As Date

TargetDate = Range("B6").Value

For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 1 'i=2 because dats in OVERVIEW stars at row 2, and Column A
    TargetSheet = Range("A" & i).Value

    'first, we make sure the date from B6 exists in the target worksheet counting
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        If .CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("A:A"), TargetDate) > 0 Then
            TargetRow = .Match(CDbl(TargetDate), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("A:A"), 0)
            Range("B" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("B" & TargetRow).Value 'IN value
            Range("C" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("C" & TargetRow).Value 'IN value
            Range("D" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("D" & TargetRow).Value 'IN value
        End If
    End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End sub
```

And after executing this code I get in OVERVIEW:

[image]

Now I want to export some values to data, and I use this code:

```
Sub EXPORT_DATA()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim TargetRow As Long
Dim TargetSheet As String
Dim TargetDate As Date

TargetDate = Range("B6").Value

For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 1 'i=2 because dats in OVERVIEW stars at row 2, and Column A
    TargetSheet = Range("A" & i).Value

    'first, we make sure the date from B6 exists in the target worksheet counting
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        If .CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("A:A"), TargetDate) > 0 Then
            TargetRow = .Match(CDbl(TargetDate), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("A:A"), 0)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("B" & TargetRow).Value = Range("B" & i).Value 'IN value
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("C" & TargetRow).Value = Range("C" & i).Value 'OUT value
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("D" & TargetRow).Value = Range("D" & i).Value 'EXTRA value
        End If
    End With
Next i

MsgBox "data exported"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And after executing code, check new data (yellow rows):
[image]

Hope this helps a litte bit and you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The problem with this solution is that it does not save the data in the apple/banana/pear tabs if I change the data. So if I fill in data for In, Out and Extra and select 18-1-2019, it will properly be copied to the specific sheet, but if I now want to use the same overview sheet and fill in different in/Out/Extra data and a different date, the previous copied data will not be there anymore. You understand what I mean?

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood your question, and forgot totally about the storing new data part. Sorry about that.

Comment: Please, @Sander_H ,check updated answer with IMPORT and EXPORT solutions.

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you for your help. I'm now gonna try to figure out what you have done. If I have any questions, I'll let you know!

Comment: Glad to help @Sander_H , If you get this to work, then please, mark it as correct so the question can be closed. Thanks.